# how to do cumulative sum datewise for particular state using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I have COVID India dataset which has daily cases. I want to aggregate daily cases to get cumulative datewise result for particular state.

Covid data set of India having daily confirmed, daily deaths and daily recovered cases for all the states:

[image]

Later I performed 'groupby' to the dataframe

```
statewise_daily.groupby(['State','Date'])['dailyconfirmed','dailydeaths','dailyrecovered'].sum().sort_values(['State','Date']).reset_index()
```

After that what should be done to get cumulative confirmed, deaths and recovered cases?

Can anyone please let me know.

Comment: Can you share (i.e. paste) terminal output  of the dataframe instead of an image?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential solution :

Firstly, convert `Date` into `datetime` format and make it `index` of the dataframe. This can be directly achieved through `read_csv` method :

```
statewise_daily=pd.read_csv('india-covid.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col=['Date'])
```

Next, you can use the your `pandas` code with minor changes together with `resample` method :

```
statewise_daily.groupby(['State'])['dailyconfirmed','dailydeaths','dailyrecovered'].resample('1D').sum().sort_values(['State']).reset_index()
```